# How do I find TV resolution from Google Chromecast iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, chromecast, google-cast

I am writing an app that uses the Google Cast iOS SDK to play video on a Chromecast device.

I have a choice of resolutions for the video URL I can play. I would ideally like to match the resolution of the video URL to the TV connected to the Chromecast device.

Can I discover what the resolution of the connected display device is via an API in the SDK? Or, can I assume that the Chromecast device will always output to a known resolution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [December 5, 2016 Release Note](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/release-notes), you can use [GCKMediaStatus.videoInfo](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/ios/interface_g_c_k_media_status#afda90a92cefa41acec3d1c47013cee6f) to enable your app to know the resolution of the currently playing media.

> **4K video format**: Added a new property GCKMediaStatus.videoInfo to
>   enable your app to know the resolution of the currently playing media.
>   This property gets the current instance of GCKVideoInfo, a new class.
>   This instance contains the type of HDR TV format and the height and
>   width in pixels. Variants of 4K format are indicated in the hdrType
>   property by enum values GCKVideoInfoHDRType. See 4k Video Format.

Comment: When I saw the videoInfo property I understood it to be the resolution of the media item being played; that is the movie itself.

The Chromecast might drive the display at a different resolution than the movie being played and handle up/down scaling. For example, I might play a 1080p movie stream on a 4k monitor, and Chromecast will still output a 4k signal.

What I want to do is find out the native resolution of the display, and load a movie which matches that resolution.